# Non-numeric argument to binary operator in Shiny using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, gis, shapefile

I am writing my first Shiny app trying to port a code for plotting maps of Spain into a Shiny app that anyone with no knowledge of R can use.

Lately I have come up with a problem when trying to alter a ggplot returned by a function.

I will post a simplified version of my code.

I first have a function in **helper.R** that takes various inputs from the ui and returns a gg and a dataframe:

```
graphing=function(datax,setter,selCCAA,varsel){
  map=readShapeSpatial('prov_map.shp')
  map@data$CodProv=as.integer(map@data$CodProv)
  map@data=merge(map@data,datax,by.x='CodProv',by.y='CodProv',sort=F) 
  map@data$id=rownames(map@data)
  map.points=fortify(map,region='id')
  map.df=join(map.points,map@data,by='id')
  map.df$Cd_CCAAint=as.integer(map.df$Cd_CCAA)

if(varsel=="-"){return (NULL)}
else {
  if (setter==0){
    mapa=ggplot(map.df)+
      aes_string("long","lat",group="group",fill=varsel)+
      geom_polygon()+
      geom_path(color='white')+
      coord_equal()
    return(list(mapa,map.df))
  }
  else {
    map.dfx<-subset(map.df,map.df$Cd_CCAAint==selCCAA)
    mapa=ggplot(map.dfx)+
      aes_string("long","lat",group="group",fill=varsel)+
      geom_polygon()+
      geom_path(color='white')+
      coord_equal()
    return(list(mapa,map.dfx))
  }
}
}
```

Then, in **server.R**, I take the gg that is returned by the function and add more lines to it so the user can personalize the graphs' colors, midpoint etc.

```
output$plot=renderPlot({

mapa=graphing(dataini,input$setter,input$selCCAA,input$varsel)

grafico=mapa[[1]]+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low='#89D1F3',high='#006EC1')+
  theme(legend.position='bottom',axis.title.x=element_blank(),
             axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),axis.text=element_blank(),
             panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank())

grafico

 })
```

When I run the app including the line scale_fill_gradient2 or any type of geom I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in +: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The error does not appear when I just include the theme.

Up to now, the two lines had been included in the graphing function and the App had been running perfectly*, but I need them to be in server.R so the graph can be personalized as stated before.

*:that version of the App can be tested using runGitHub("Mapas_BBVA_provincias","IArchondo"). Any help with the display of spanish characters such as ñ in the ui, would be extremely welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the error you get from

```
NULL + scale_fill_gradient2(low='#89D1F3',high='#006EC1')
```

Since your graphing function begins with `if(varsel=="-"){return (NULL)}`, my guess is this error is created when `varsel` is `"-"`. Try returning a blank `ggplot` object instead when nothing is selected.

```
if(varsel=="-"){return (ggplot())}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn´t realize that. Thanks a lot!